# Move SharePoint Metadata to sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, cross-site-publishing, metalogix

- We are using Managed Meta data in SharePoint 2016 with Cross Site
  Publishing Feature.
- And now client decided to move our SharePoint 2016 to SharePoint
  Online. I a doing POC to know the list of options including the 
  tools(Sharegate,Metalogix) which are best suitable for
  migration and accomplish this feature.

Can any one please guide me in achieving this.

Thanks & Regards,

SharePoint_Beginner

Comment: I have used Sharegate tool and it can migrate manage metadata from OnPrem to Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To migrate managed metadata from SharePoint 2016 to SharePoint online, you could export the metadata to CSV file in SharePoint 2016 and import the metadata from the CSV file in SharePoint online.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[Export SharePoint MetaData to CSV along with their Guids.](https://piyushksingh.com/2015/06/19/export-sharepoint-metadata-to-csv-along-with-their-guids/)

[PowerShell for SharePoint 2013: Export TermSet to CSV.](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/PowerShell-for-SharePoint-a838b5d0)

[Import term sets.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-term-sets-168fbc86-7fce-4288-9a1f-b83fc3921c18)